# Hyperref referring to the wrong label

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, counters

I have this code in LaTeX and I am dealing with some dynamic work with labels and references. This code works - first reference references to the first text and second to the second but I want to reset the `contentCounter` within each section.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{contentCounter}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}

\newcommand{\inserttext}{%
    \refstepcounter{contentCounter}
    \par This is inserted text widh ID \thesection.\thecontentCounter. \\
    \label{text:\thesection.\thecontentCounter}
}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{section}{1}
\inserttext

\setcounter{section}{2}
\inserttext

\newpage
\textbf{References}

\setcounter{section}{1}
\hyperref[text:\thesection.1]{first text}

\setcounter{section}{2}
\hyperref[text:\thesection.2]{second text}

\end{document}
```

I tried to reset the counter but second reference is not working. Where's the problem? Thank you.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{contentCounter}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}

\newcommand{\inserttext}{%
    \refstepcounter{contentCounter}
    \par This is inserted text with the ID \thesection.\thecontentCounter. \\
    \label{text:\thesection.\thecontentCounter}
}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{section}{1}
\inserttext

\setcounter{section}{2}
\setcounter{contentCounter}{0}
\inserttext

\newpage
\textbf{References}

\setcounter{section}{1}
\hyperref[text:\thesection.1]{first text}

\setcounter{section}{2}
\hyperref[text:\thesection.1]{second text}

\end{document}
```

Comment: To set a 'sub'-counter, the normal syntax is: `\newcounter{countername}[supercounter]` (where `supercounter` here probably should be `section`).

Comment: @jon: So simple solution! Thank you very much.

Comment: @jon, can you convert your comment to answer?

Comment: `\label{text:\thesection.\thecontentCounter}` is _very_ odd. do you just have this in the test file or are you really using labels based on the counter value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(If this is not a duplicate....)

All that is needed in this case is to use the optional argument to `\newcounter`:

```
\newcounter{contentCounter}[section]
```

Where the `[section]` indicates that `contentCounter` should be reset to zero with each use of `\section`.

Note that if you need to modify a counter initially defined without the optional argument (or, conversely, to modify a counter defined with the optional argument), you can use the `chngcntr` package and its commands: `\counterwithin` and `\counterwithout`. Both commands include a 'starred' variant, which suppresses redefinition of the related `\the<counter>` commands.